# Algorithm2e: What is the recommended method to change the caption of ONE algorithm?

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

I want to read the caption of one of my algorithms typeset by `algorithm2e` to read `Listing` instead of the default `algorithm`.

What is the recommended/best way to achieve this?

**I actually have a working solution**, but I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it and wonder if it might come back and **bite me** some place: simply use `algorithmcfname` to change the caption to `Listing` and then change it back to `Algorithm` after the potion that should use a different caption, like so:

```
\renewcommand*{\algorithmcfname}{Listing}
\begin{algorithm}
....
\end{algorithm}
\renewcommand*{\algorithmcfname}{Algorithm}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\SetAlgorithmName{Listing}` inside the `algorithm` environment. Unfortunately, \autoref is going to translate always to algorithm #.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}


\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
        test
        \caption{algo 1}
    \end{algorithm}


    \begin{algorithm}
        \SetAlgorithmName{Listing}
        test
        \caption{algo 2}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm}
        test
        \caption{algo 3}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]